Moodle Use Webservice for store data
I'm currently trying to write data from the app into the database. I'm using the web service for this.
However, I get the following error message and the documentation is, in my opinion, very sparse.

core_external\external_multiple_structure::__ construct(): Argument #1
($Content) must be of type  core_external\external_description, array
given, called in

The relevant line is the following:
'eintraege' => new external_multiple_structure([

The complete function is:
public static function execute_returns(): external_single_structure {
        return new external_single_structure([
            'eintraege' => new external_multiple_structure([
                    'fach' => new external_value(PARAM_INT, 'FachID'),
                    'datum' => new external_value(PARAM_RAW, 'Datum des Eintrags'),
                    'ustdbis' => new external_value(PARAM_INT, 'USTD bis'),
                    'ustdvon' => new external_value(PARAM_INT, 'USTD von'),
                    'eintrag' => new external_value(PARAM_TEXT, 'Eintrag'),
            ])
        ]);
    }

I would be very grateful for any help and thank you very much for that!
I tried the following variations:
`A parameter can be described as:
a list => external_multiple_structure
an object => external_single_structure
a primary type => external_value`
As described here:
https://moodledev.io/docs/4.5/apis/subsystems/external/writing-a-service

Looking at the docs you provided, I can see that you're passing the parameters wrong.
The following line in your case:
'eintraege' => new external_multiple_structure([
   'fach' => new external_value(PARAM_INT, 'FachID'),
   //etc
])

should return a new external_single_structure instance as well, but in your case, it's just returning the array. Try to make it like this:
public static function execute_returns(): external_single_structure {
    return new external_single_structure([
        'eintraege' => new external_multiple_structure(
            new external_single_structure([
                'fach' => new external_value(PARAM_INT, 'FachID'),
                'datum' => new external_value(PARAM_RAW, 'Datum des Eintrags'),
                'ustdbis' => new external_value(PARAM_INT, 'USTD bis'),
                'ustdvon' => new external_value(PARAM_INT, 'USTD von'),
                'eintrag' => new external_value(PARAM_TEXT, 'Eintrag'),
            ])
        )
    ]);
}


Thank you very much for your help. I'm one step further now. However, I'm now getting the error message:
Invalid parameter value (fach => Invalid parameter value (Only arrays accepted. The bad value is: '1').
I think it's because of the template.
<ion-select placeholder="Select subject" [(ngModel)]="CONTENT_OTHERDATA.fach" value="1"> <%#faecher%> <ion-select-option value="<% id%>"><% fach %></ion-select-option> <%/faecher%> </ion-select>

Well, this now sounds like a different issue. You can create a separate question for that one, and include any relevant code that could cause this error. If this answer helped you in any way, please mark it accordingly. Thanks :)
